# Incorrect heading size of list generated with tocloft package

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I'm new to latex and would appreciate some help with a problem I am having with generating a list of equations using the tocloft package. I would like the list to appear as the \listoftables \listoffigures functions appear. Im using the article document class and the tocloft package to generate a new list.

```
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{figure}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{2.5em}`

%followed by :

\section*{List of Illustrations}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Illustrations} 
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{List of Figures} 
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{List of Tables}
\listofmyequations
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{List of Equations}`
```

this generates [image]

Comment: Do `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}`, so the package doesn't seize the initiative and change the chapter headings.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a suggestion using `tocbasic` instead `tocloft`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\usepackage{scrbase}
\renewcommand*{\tableofcontents}{\listoftoc[{\contentsname}]{toc}}
\renewcommand*{\listoffigures}{\listoftoc[{\listfigurename}]{lof}}
\renewcommand*{\listoftables}{\listoftoc[{\listtablename}]{lot}}

\DeclareNewTOC[
  type=myequation,
  name=Equation,
  listname={List of Equations},
  tocentrynumwidth=2.3em,% like figures and tables
  tocentryindent=1.5em,% like figures and tables
]{equ}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
  \addxcontentsline{equ}{myequation}[\theequation]{#1}}

\setuptoc{lof}{leveldown,totoc}
\setuptoc{lot}{leveldown,totoc}
\setuptoc{equ}{leveldown,totoc}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section*{List of Illustrations}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Illustrations} 
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\listofmyequations
\section{A Section}
\blindtext
\begin{table}[htb]
  \centering\huge Table
  \caption{First table}
\end{table}
\Blindtext
\begin{table}[htb]
  \centering\centering\huge Table
  \caption{Second table}
\end{table}
\blindtext
\begin{equation}
  a^2+b^2=c^2
  \myequations{A first equation}
\end{equation}
\section{A second section}
\Blindtext
\begin{table}[htb]
  \centering\centering\huge Table
  \caption{Third table}
\end{table}
\Blindtext
\begin{equation}
  h=pq
  \myequations{A second equation}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]