# How to move center and reducing fontsize the chapter title "Contents" and "List of Appendices"?

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, titles

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[left=4 cm,right=3cm,top=4cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{tocloft}
% code for List of Appendices
\newcommand{\listappendicesname}{List of Appendices}
\newlistof{appendix}{app}{\listappendicesname}
% new command for appendix sections
\newcommand{\appsection}[1]{\section{#1}%
    \addcontentsline{app}{appendix}{Appendix \protect\numberline{\thesection}#1}\par}

\titleformat{\chapter}
[display]
{\center\bfseries}
{\large\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}{1pt}{\large}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0cm}{-1.2cm}{0.7cm}

\titleformat{\section}
[hang]
{\bfseries}
{\bfseries\thesection}{1ex}{\bfseries}

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
linefill=\bfseries\TOCLineLeaderFill,
beforeskip=2pt,
entrynumberformat=\chapterprefixintoc,
dynnumwidth
]{tocline}{chapter}

\newcommand*\chapterprefixintoc[1]
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}~#1\enskip}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \tableofcontents
    
    \newpage
    % print list of appendices and add title to the ToC
    \listofappendix \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listappendicesname}
    
    \mainmatter
    \chapter{ABC}
    \section{First}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \section{Second}
    \lipsum[3-4]
    
    \chapter*{APPENDIX}
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
    \titleformat{\section}
    {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{Appendix~\thesection.}{1em}{}
    %%%%%    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{APPENDICES} % don't add to ToC
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}} % No sections in ToC
    \appsection{First Appendix}
    \lipsum[4-4]
    
    \appsection{Second Appendix}
    \lipsum[3-3]
\end{document}
```

I want to move center the chapter title "Contents" and "List of Appendices". I also want to reduce the font size the chapter title "Contents" and "List of Appendices" same as "Chapter 1".

[image]

[image]

How to do it?

Comment: This was not the appearance you wanted in your question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/572170 If you had said that this was what you wanted I would have told you how to do it. Did you read the `tocloft` documentation?

Comment: This is different question of tex.stackexchange.com/questions/572170.  I have added `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}`, and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I look at @egreg comment from [Incorrect heading size of list generated with tocloft package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307155/incorrect-heading-size-of-list-generated-with-tocloft-package), just adding `[titles]` in `tocloft` package, i.e. `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}` it can solve my problem.

[image]

[image]